# Convert a scala.util.Try to a scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, future

I started migrating my Scala 2.11 code base to Scala 2.12. In my application I had a method that looked like this:

```
Future {
  someMethodReturningTry()
} onSuccess {
  case Success(result) => processResult()
  case Failure(reason) => log.error(s"Couldn't do it: ${reason.getMessage}")
}
```

Now, if you compile this with Scala 2.12, you'll get:

> method onSuccess in trait Future is deprecated (since 2.12.0): use `foreach` or `onComplete` instead (keep in mind that they take total rather than partial functions)

So I started exploring how I could solve this in an elegant way.

The `someMethodReturningTry()` method *really* should return a `Try[]`, since it involves parsing some text structure and that might fail, so I prefer to keep the return type for that method the same.

The best I could think of is

```
Future {
  someMethodReturningTry()
} flatMap {
  case Success(result) => Future.successful(result)
  case Failure(reason) => Future.failed(reason)
} onComplete {
  case Success(result) => processResult()
  case Failure(reason) => log.error(s"Couldn't do it: ${reason.getMessage}")
}
```

But that feels a bit redundant: creating a `Future` just to model the fact that something in the future (which already is captured inside a `Future`) went well.

This approach creates an extra `Future` which I hope to get rid of, but I can't figure out how. Any suggestions?

Comment: `Future.fromTry` ?

Comment: `Future.fromTry` isn't a good option for me, since it doesn't work asynchronously. It first invokes the method that yields the `Try` and only *then* creates the promise.

Comment: A `Try` isn't async anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you don't just...

```
Future {
  someMethodReturningTry() match {
    case Success(result) => processResult(result)
    case Failure(reason) => log.error(s"Couldn't do it: ${reason.getMessage}")
  }
}
```

You're free to handle, or ignore, the `Future` failure separately.

Comment: Well, yes, that makes sense! It doesn't create unnecessary deep structures and it's clear to read - exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust your pattern matching in the following way:

```
Future {
  someMethodReturningTry()
} onComplete {
  case Success(Success(result)) => processResult()
  case Success(Failure(reason)) => log.error(s"Couldn't do it: ${reason.getMessage}")
  case Failure(reason) =>
    log.error(s"The future failed: ${reason.getMessage}")
    // or do nothing
}
```

Note that the `onSuccess` callback is executed only if the `Future` succeeds, so your original code didn't do anything if the `Future` contained an exception. If that is your intent, you can leave the `case Failure(reason) =>` clause above blank (but it's probably more helpful to retain the error logging as shown).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Good catch about the `onSuccess`; the `someMethodReturningTry()` did some logging when it would return `Failure`, but this method was free to ignore that failure.
I'm wondering, can I somehow get rid of the `Success[Success[...]]` structure? It also feels a bit redundant, too...

Comment: @mthmulders `onComplete { _.flatten match { case Success(result) => ... case Failure(reason) => ... }}`.